# How to display answers in index django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am trying to display questions and answer count in respective questions, all in the home page. How do I do it?

Models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ('Math', 'Math'),
        ('Geography', 'Geography'),
        ('Biology', 'Biology'),
        ('Physics', 'Physics'),
        ('Chemistry', 'Chemistry'),
        ('Health', 'Health'),
        ('Computer Science', 'Computer Science'),
        ('History', 'History'),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=3000)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=140, unique=True)
    date = models.DateField(null=True, default=datetime.date.today)
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=50, default=None, null=True)
    satisfied = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def _get_unique_slug(self):
        slug = slugify(self.title)
        unique_slug = slug
        num = 1
        while Question.objects.filter(slug=unique_slug).exists():
            unique_slug = '{}-{}'.format(slug, num)
            num += 1
        return unique_slug

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = self._get_unique_slug()
        super().save()

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None)
    answer = models.TextField(max_length=3000, null=True)
    posted_on = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.now().date())
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    questions = Question.objects.all().order_by("-date")
    numbers = Question.objects.all().count()
    numbers2 = Answer.objects.all().count()
    total_users = User.objects.all().count()
    # PAGINATION ===============================
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)

    paginator = Paginator(questions, 10)
    try:
        questions = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        questions = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        questions = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    # counting answers on specific questions

    empty = []
    for a in  Answer.objects.raw('SELECT id, question_id FROM main_answer'):
        idd = a.id
        question_id = (a.question_id)
        empty.append(str(question_id))
    repeatition = Counter(empty)
    i = 0
    trend_list = []
    for x in range(len(repeatition)):
        new = repeatition.most_common()[i][0]
        trend_list.append(new)
        i += 1
    trend = Question.objects.get(id=trend_list[0])
    print(trend_list)
    print(trend)
    # getting the answers to all questions in the front page

    # search the questions ============
    query= request.GET.get("q")
    if query:
        results = Question.objects.all()
        questions = results.filter(title__icontains=query)

    context = {
        'questions': questions,
        'numbers': numbers,
        'numbers2': numbers2,
        'total_users': total_users,
        'trend': trend,

    }
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', context)
```

So what i need is to display questions and the number of answers in specific question.
For Example, in home page, I have all the questions displayed, what I want is to display the number on those questions.

What is Time? Answers: count of answers.

How can I do this? Please help.
[image: Image for the homepage]

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, do you mean that you want the number of answers for each question?

Comment: @at14 Yes that's what I want

Comment: Alasdair has the answer, also on a side note, I don't see why you are using Raw queries for something as simple as a select *, it is not recommended to use Raw queries unless you really have to

Comment: @at14 Oh about that I had not used raw queries before in django, so I was testing. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [annotate your queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) with the number of answers:

```
from django.db.models import Count
results = Question.objects.annotate(num_answers=Count('answer'))
```

Then you can access `question.num_answers` as you loop through the queryset:

```
{% for question in questions %}
    {{ question.title }}
    {{ question.num_answers }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I am getting Answer:

Comment: When I use {{ question.num_answers }}, it returns blank.

Comment: @Alasdair edit the for loop, make it {% for question in questions %}, your qs and each instance of the qs are being referred to by the same name "question"

Comment: Then you didn't call `annotate()` on the queryset that you passed through to your template.

Comment: @at14 beat you to it

Comment: Hey thanks, it was my fault. I figured it out. Thanks a lot